# How can i apply arithmetic operation with total value of first calculation in JQuery calculator

Tags: jquery, calculator

I am trying to say how I can do this operation in this calculator.for example if I do this calculation in this calculator 2 + 2 = 4, in this calculation answer is 4, I want to do new calculation with the answer of the previous equation. for example, a previous equation answer is 4 and I want this 2 + 2 = 4 then 4 + 2 = 6 .

```
<body>
    <input type="text" class="input">
    <button class="oprator" id="butn4">4</button>
    <button class="oprator" id="butn6">6</button>
    <button id="butnplus">+</button>
    <button id="equal">=</button>
</body>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var evaluated = false;
        $(".oprator").click(function () {
            const val = evaluated ? $(this).text() : ($(".input").val() + $(this).text())
            $(".input").val(val)
            evaluated = false;
        });

        $("#butnplus").click(function () {
            $(".input").val($(".input").val() + $("#butnplus").text())
        });
        $("#equal").click(function () {
            $(".input").val((eval($(".input").val())))
            evaluated = true;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use eval function to evaluate your expression.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#butnplus").click(function () {
           if($(".input").val()=="")
              return false;
           else{
              $(".input").val($(".input").val() + $(this).text())
           }
        });
         $("#butn4").click(function () {
             if($(".input").val()=="")
               $(".input").val($(this).text())
           else{
              $(".input").val($(".input").val() + $(this).text())
           }
        });
        $("#butn6").click(function () {
           if($(".input").val()=="")
               $(".input").val($(this).text())
           else{
              $(".input").val($(".input").val() + $(this).text())
           }
        });
        $("#equal").click(function () {
            $(".input").val(eval($(".input").val()))
        });
     
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <input type="text" class="input">
    <button class="oprator" id="butn4">4</button>
    <button class="oprator" id="butn6">6</button>
    <button id="butnplus">+</button>
    <button id="equal">=</button>
</body>
```